# compressor running constantly but ice not dropping

Tags: repair

the compressor on our refrigerator freezer quit running so we replaced the relay. now the compressor has been running for over 21 hours. the ice maker has made ice but has not dropped the ice. what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the ice gets stuck in the tray -- there's supposed to be a heater that melts the outside of the ice so it can be pushed out.

Check if there is ice in the icemaking tray.

When this happens, I use a hairdryer to loosen the individual crescents, and push them out with a wooden spoon handle. The cycle usually resets and starts producing ice normally afterwards.